# What would a rough estimate of the global climate of an earth be like if lit by a geosynchronous ring instead of a point source?

Tags: science-based, planets, climate

**Welcome to fantasy earth: like Earth in all the same ways, with the exception that the sun you know has been replaced with a ring you don't.**

What would the climate of Earth be if the sun was replaced with a ring ("magic", for however much it's functioning matters) with the following properties:

- In geosynchronous (not geostationary!) orbit, at 35.800 km-ish height, and so taking 24 hours to orbit fantasy earth.
- Orbiting at an inclination of 24 degrees.
- Infinitely thin (like I said, magic). Imagine a string wrapped around the Earth and you'll get the idea. This infinitely thin part is flavor, more than anything else. It's a single magic loop of infinitely thin yarn outputting a magical amount of light around the planet.
- Radiating light at about 0.007 the degree of brightness of the sun, with the same electromagnetic output of the sun, both in respect of what wavelengths are produced, as well as the irradiance that any individual area experiences, within the range of what's currently experienced by Earth.

**Notes**:

- I'm assuming that from the perspective of the Earth's surface, the ring would move in a figure 8 pattern, with the net result being a ring weaving around it throughout the day
- Half of the northern and southern hemispheres would likely experience night, and half day at the same time—what impact that would have on the climate, I don't know.
- I'm assuming that some latitudes would experience a steady degree of irradiance, and so result in more static climate zones, but I'm not 100% certain regarding such things.

**Addendum**: a very rough estimate is fine, no extensive modeling is required, vibes will suffice.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty picturing it. What's meant by "infinitly thin?" Is this a ring shaped like Saturn's rings, and if so how big is it?

Comment: @BMF, The ring itself itsn't a physical object is probably more apt, though it emits light and acts like one. Imagine a string wrapping around the earth, and you'll get the idea. Its radius is infinitely thin because its magic, but thats just flavour

Comment: What is the diameter of the ring? If this is a planetary ring (like one of Saturn's rings), then the orbital period won't matter. You'll always have the same percentage of the ring over any longitude. If this is a ring like a Bishop ring, then it would be functionally identical to a spot-source of light. I'm not sure what the orbital stability would be for something in between. Could you specify?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can I presume that the planet has always been that way, like evolved with this arrangement, or is this a sudden change?

Comment: That comment by the automated Community BOT means your question has failed one or more of Stack Exchange's minimum quality rules. It wasn't the use of the [tag:hard-science] tag for an entirely fictional construction that we have no real world analogues to draw from to rationalize, and it's not that you're asking an off-topic [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609). It is that you're asking something that's a bit vague and very much too broad. Climate is the hardest question type on this Stack. Fictional climate is even harder. And you want it all.

Comment: @Robbert Rapplean You can presume its always been that way

Comment: First off geosynchronous and geostationary both mean the same thing .. second off the length of time it takes to orbit is irrelevant, it's a ring, it will be over every point of it's orbit at all times no matter what the orbit speed is or isn't, or is it supposed to be flipping end to end around the planet?

Comment: @Pelinore: No, [geosynchronous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geosynchronous_orbit) and [geostationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostationary_orbit) do not mean the same thing. There are many geosynchronous orbits, but only one geostationary orbit.

Comment: @AlexP Hmm, OK, there's only one equator, but it's not important to the question, the ring will still appear to be stationary over every point on its orbit from the surface.

Comment: @Pelinore: No it won't. Seen from a point on the Equator, the ring will appear as a chord with fixed points east and west and the middle oscillating from 66° north to 66° south with a period of one day. From a point at 24° north, the ring will appear as a band stretching east to west through the zenith once per day, moving down to an east-to-west  band culminating at 48° south and then rising up to the zenith again. From a point at 42° north, the ring will appear as a eastish-to-westish band culminating at 48° south once per day, then go down south until it sets completely before rising again.

Comment: @AlexP Gah! Yep, only an orbit around the equator is going to look entirely stationary, makes it a little more complex than I was thinking, there'll be a daily fluctuation in the amount of energy received in some areas in a band that will be wider the greater the inclination of the orbit is, the land directly below it will get the same at all times but to either side their will be a small shift back and forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous immediate and obvious differences that I can think of, mostly describing plant life, weather, and geology. I have to admit that my imagination only extends to things that such a model would eliminate from our current system.

I'm sure that everyone here can tell you about Hadley cells, and how the rotation of the earth creates high-altitude warm currents from the equator up to about 30 degrees. That would still happen, but to a lesser extent.

You won't see the massive heat pump of heat-expanded air driving wind currents around the planet, so there would be less overall wind. The plants would be more spindly because gusts that could knock them down would be once-in-a-lifetime events.

It occurs to me that, due to consistent heating, there would probably be places on the planet that it rained constantly due to prevailing winds running into mountains creating a watershed. These rainy areas would probably dig furrows through mountains the same way that rivers make oxbows in our world.

You won't see the day/night cycle raising temperatures in the day, then dumping water when the temperature drops below the dew point. Thus, much, much less precipitation, which means less erosion wearing mountains down into arable soil and fewer, narrower rivers. Maybe more of the plants would draw water from the air like tillandsia.

Right now, many plants will twist to follow the sun, getting the most out of the light. If it's always in the same direction (like in the temperate zones), then much of the vegetation would create a vertical wall of leaves pointing towards the equator. Equatorial plants might have a little phototropism, but that would be up to evolution.

Since you have consistent illumination, you will no longer have seasons. Most Earth plants use this to trigger their growth/reproduction cycles, so you'd have to think of something else.

Comment: *"Constant illumination:"* There will be always light between 66° latitude south and 66° latitude north, but far from constant. Above 66° latitude north and below 66° latitude south there will be a daily cycle of light and darkness.

Comment: @AlexP, fair point, but you're talking about the area that, on Earth, is the Arctic Circle. I don't think that the ring-sun would change the effect that the high angle of incidence has on heat absorption. I'm sure that some plants would specialize up there, but I wouldn't expect them to dominate the ecosystem. If they actually _depend_ on the day/night cycle, they wouldn't be able to survive in non-arctic climates.

Comment: I'm going to wait for six hours before checking your response per guidelines

Comment: Thank you! I thought of another one: No sun-tides, and you would have a hard time seeing a moon.